# How can I draw bar graph in python on aggregated data?

Tags: python, visualization, pandas, matplotlib

Normally when I draw bar plot its simple as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
import seaborn as sb

%matplotlib inline
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 5, 4
sb.set_style('whitegrid')

x = range(1, 10)
y = [1,2,3,4,0.5,4,3,2,1]

plt.bar(x, y)
```

When I aggregate data on basis of `age` feature with the following command

```
data_ag = data.groupby('age')['age'].count()
```

It returns the output that is the people belonging to a particular age e.g. 11 people with age 22 years.

```
age
22     11
23      8
27     28
28      1
29     70
30     13
31     45
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

How can I treat those as `x` and `y` points to draw a bar plot?

```
x = # what should I write here for age data
y = # what for count 

plt.bar(x, y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue using `size()` and `reset_index()` functions.

```
g1 = data.groupby( ["age"] ).size().reset_index(name='count')

x= g1['count']
y=g1['age']

plt.bar(x, y)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series(data=[11, 8, 28, 1, 70, 13, 45],
               index=[22, 23, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
               name="age").rename_axis("age", axis=0)

x = df.index
y = df.values

plt.bar(x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: I had a different type of data (returned by aggregate function) not a Series data.. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @MutafafWahhaj, what makes you think what you were working with was not a `Series`?